# cant install WINE on ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, wine

It is my terminal command

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

and it is my answer

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 5.21~bionic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm getting confuse how to install wine on Ubuntu 18.04 because I need that

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1290467/edit) to include the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Answer (score 1):

Why use the "staging" version? Just run:

`sudo apt install wine`